# Azure Notification Hub to Apple and Android

Tags: ios, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

We build an iOS app using Apple Push Notification feature. We integrated everything the Apple docs told including provisioning profiles etc... A test in development mode worked fine with Apple tools. Same should be in near future with Google, but I´m talking here just about iOS implementation...

Our backend on Azure collects the registration ids from all iOS apps proper. I mean: We are storing the token retrieved from registration directly at Apple services.

Now we want to use Azure to send Push Notifications to all our apps. But I´m confused from reading the Microsoft documentation:

Must my mobile apps register to Apple or to Microsoft with corresponding SDK?

We don't use the MS SDK on app side. We just register at Apple. Can we send Push Notifications to our iOS apps (just simple broadcast to *all* registered apps) with Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Our backend on Azure collects the registration ids from all iOS apps proper. I mean: We are storing the token retrieved from registration directly at Apple services.

Where are you storing them? You have to store/register the device tokens at your Azure Notification Hub.

> Must my mobile apps register to Apple or to Microsoft with corresponding SDK?

Your app has to get a device token from APNS and then register this token at your Azure Notification Hub, so basically you have to do both.

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management#what-is-device-registration). On a high level the whole process looks like this:

[image]

> We don't use the MS SDK on app side.

You don't have to use the SDK, you can use the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Dn530746.aspx).